# Detach entity in Spring Data

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm using Spring Data and i have such class structure:

```
A has-a B  and  B has-a List<C>
```

and code:

```
List<A> aList= aRepository.findAll();
aList.forEach(a-> a.getB().setC(null));
```

I don't need List of C's in frontend (in this particular scenario). But when I set C as null, the `EntityManager` is not in detached state and it sets `C` as `null` in the database. How to detach entities in a `List` after I retrieve them? I tried this:

```
EntityManager em=entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
aList.forEach(a -> em.detach(a) ......);
```

But it didn't work. Any suggestions?

**EDIT:**

Here's the actual entities (without unnecessary fields):

`Session` (Class A in above example):

```
@Entity
public class AuthSession {
    private AuthUser user;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id",foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_auth_user_id"))

    public AuthUser getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(AuthUser user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```

`User` (class B in above example):

```
@Entity
public class AuthUser {

    private Set<AuthRole> roles;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name = "USER_ROLE_LINK", 
        schema = "iapauth", 
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), 
        foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_user_id"), 
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"), 
        inverseForeignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_role_fk"))
    public Set<AuthRole> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(Set<AuthRole> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }
```

`Role` (Class C in above example):

```
@Entity
public class AuthRole{}
```

I have a code to add roles to user (new entries in auto-generated link-table "USER_ROLE_LINK"). It works fine. And i have this code to retrieve all sessions:

```
EntityManager em=entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
List<AuthSession> sessions=sessionRepo.findAll();
sessions.forEach(x->{
    em.detach(x);
    AuthUser user=x.getUser();
    if(user!=null) user.setRoles(null);
});
return sessions;
```

But after this code executes, entries in `user-role` table (those whose users are in current session) are deleted.

Comment: This is the way to do it. Could you provide some example code with actual instances where one can see this? Which entities are you detaching? Are they referenced by other entities managed by the `EntityManager`? How does your cascade configuration look like?

Comment: I think you need to iterate over the list of C and detach that individually..

Comment: @Jens Schauder  See the edit above

Comment: use join with query with DTO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the idea of detaching is a correct one, you are detaching the wrong entities.

With this code

```
List<AuthSession> sessions=sessionRepo.findAll();
sessions.forEach(x->{
    em.detach(x);
    AuthUser user=x.getUser();
    if(user!=null) user.setRoles(null);
});
```

All the `AuthUser`s referenced by the `AuthSession` are still managed by the `EntityManager` (i.e. not detached). You need to either explicitly detach them or add a cascade configuration to `AuthSession.user`

See: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bnbqm/index.html

Also as  Mukhamedali Zhadigerov describes in the comments one should use an injected `EntityManager`.

Comment: By 'explicitly detach them' you mean `em.detach(user)`  within forEach loop?

Comment: No, it didn't work. I think I need to detach USER_ROLE entity (which doesn't exist, as it is auto-created) somehow.

Comment: By the way, i added `e.contains(ses.getUser())` and it returned false

Comment: I think i'm not getting the EntityManager properly because even `e.contains(ses)` returns false.

Comment: Ok, it turned out that i was getting the EntityManager in improper way. I added `@PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;`  and it worked. Thanks

Comment: darn, completely missed that. you still had to detach the Users right?

Comment: Yes. I detached the users as in the code above and now it works fine. I marked your answer as the correct one because "Getting the EM in the proper way" is actually out of scope of the question.